# Pivot Control inside Listbox control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like know if it's possibel to put a Pivot Control inside a Listbox. This way one of the items inside the Listbox would be a Pivot Control. Idea here is that when showing a list of photos a collection of photos could be shown as a Pivot Control inside list. I know that this might not be the best possible UX, but I'm more interested to know if it's possible at all?

At the moment I have a code that should work, but for some reason the pivot control is just empty.

Comment: can you show the xaml/code you are using?

Comment: Never mind. Found out that this is quite easy to do. Just had a mistake with the databinding part of the code.

Comment: OK, well as you mentioned, this would not follow the UX guidelines and would be quite confusing